# dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure)

Tags: mysql, nginx, debian

When I try to **install nginx** the error comes like:

```
dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
 libmysqlclient21:amd64
 nginx-full
 mysql-community-server
 libmysqlclient-dev
 mysql-server
 mysql-community-client
 mysql-client
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried a lot of solution but not solve my problem,this one of them:

```
sudo dpkg ––configure –a
```

**but it's show this error**

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-common
libmysqlclient21:amd64
mysql-community-server
libmysqlclient-dev
mysql-server
mysql-community-client
mysql-client
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I fixed the problem,**

1. nginx fix:

the problem is because of the apache2 service, I just stopped the apache2 service after that installed nginx.

```
sudo service apache2 stop

sudo install nginx
```

2. fix sub process error code (1):

I used the sips in this [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1?fbclid=IwAR2GWpoPyfJ_UflARhd6X4WyZ0DA5dd14SmMezxT7Cd1yIRj1_g_4RdYSsw) And it's worked for me.